# In the Arrowverse crossover "Invasion!" why did they believe future Barry's message to Rip was about the events in 2016?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse

Basically as the title states.

In the Arrowverse crossover "Invasion!", why did everyone (Barry included) believe that the message 2042 Flash sent to Captain Rip Hunter was in reference to the war between Earth and the Dominators, and that 2016 Barry Allen couldn't be trusted?

It's not like the message specifically mentioned the year 2016, or the Dominators themselves, so what made it so specific to that point in time?

Comment: Because 1+1=2...